# Input can fill only only 10 digits using Javascript not working on firefox why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

Input can fill only 10 digits using Javascript not working on firefox why?

Fill EG: `0258748542` I tested on chrome it's work good.
But not working on firefox Why?

How can I do this?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="ten_number" onkeyup="check_ten_number_length_up(this.value)" onkeydown="return check_ten_number_length_down(this,10);" type="number" class="feedback-input" id="ten_number" placeholder="please enter 10 digits" onchange="updateInput_ten_number(this.value)">


<span id="mySpan_ten_number"></span>

<script>
function check_ten_number_length_up(ten_number_value){
 var ten_number_value = ten_number_value.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, "");
 document.getElementById("ten_number").value = "";
 document.getElementById("ten_number").value = ten_number_value;
 var ten_number_value = document.getElementById("ten_number").value;
 
 if(ten_number_value.length==10) 
 {
  document.getElementById("ten_number").style.border = "1px solid rgba(72,72,72,0.4)";
  document.getElementById("mySpan_ten_number").innerHTML = "";
 }
 else
 {
  document.getElementById("ten_number").style.border = "1px solid red";
  document.getElementById("mySpan_ten_number").innerHTML = "please enter 10 digits";
 }
}
</script>


<script>
function updateInput_ten_number(ten_number_value){
    var ten_number_value_length = ten_number_value.length;
    if(ten_number_value_length != "10")
    {
        document.getElementById("ten_number").style.border = "1px solid red";
        document.getElementById("mySpan_ten_number").innerHTML = "please enter 10 digits";
 }
 else
 {
        document.getElementById("ten_number").style.border = "1px solid rgba(72,72,72,0.4)";
        document.getElementById("mySpan_ten_number").innerHTML = "";
 }
}
</script>

<script>
function check_ten_number_length_down(ten_number_value,max_length){
  if([8, 37,38,39,40, 46].indexOf(event.which) == -1)
  {
      return ten_number_value.value.length < max_length;
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't pass your event to the `check_ten_number_length_down()` function.
You also don't need to update the value with an empty string only to overwrite it with the old value again.

```js
function check_ten_number_length_up(ten_number_value){

 var ten_number_value = ten_number_value.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, "");
 
 if(ten_number_value.length==10) 
 {
  document.getElementById("ten_number").style.border = "1px solid rgba(72,72,72,0.4)";
  document.getElementById("mySpan_ten_number").innerHTML = "";
 }
 else
 {
  document.getElementById("ten_number").style.border = "1px solid red";
  document.getElementById("mySpan_ten_number").innerHTML = "please enter 10 digits";
 }
}

function updateInput_ten_number(ten_number_value){
    var ten_number_value_length = ten_number_value.length;
    if(ten_number_value_length != "10")
    {
        document.getElementById("ten_number").style.border = "1px solid red";
        document.getElementById("mySpan_ten_number").innerHTML = "please enter 10 digits";
 }
 else
 {
        document.getElementById("ten_number").style.border = "1px solid rgba(72,72,72,0.4)";
        document.getElementById("mySpan_ten_number").innerHTML = "";
 }
}

function check_ten_number_length_down(event, ten_number_value, max_length){
  if([8, 37,38,39,40, 46].indexOf(event.which) == -1)
  {
      return ten_number_value.value.length < max_length;
  }
}
```

```css
input[type=number] {-moz-appearance: textfield;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="ten_number" onkeyup="check_ten_number_length_up(this.value)" onkeydown="return check_ten_number_length_down(event, this, 10);" type="number" class="feedback-input" id="ten_number" placeholder="please enter 10 digits" onchange="updateInput_ten_number(this.value)">


<span id="mySpan_ten_number"></span>
```

Comment: But still cannot fill 0 on first number.

Comment: Fixed that now.

Comment: with input[type=number] {-moz-appearance: textfield;}